# Selenium Python - How to load existed profile on chrome?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

So, I want to use my existed profile on chrome to make easily to login and fetch some data from the website. So I tried this on my current codes but it doesn't load the profile for some reason,

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time

class ClientDriver:
    def __init__(self):
        self.options = Options()
        self.options.add_argument("--lang=en_US")
        self.options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
        self.options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
        self.options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
        self.options.add_argument(
            r"user-data-dir=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 1"
        )
        self.options.add_argument("--profile-directory=Profile 1")

    def check(self):
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(
            service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=self.options
        )
        driver.get("chrome://version/")
        time.sleep(100)


x = ClientDriver()
x.check()
```

As can you see on my current codes, it will redirect to `chrome://version/` to check the Profile Path and it's not `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 1` but it was `C:\Users\Users\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 1\Profile 1`. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're checking `chrome://version/` from your selenium test, of course you see a wrong path!
You should instead open a normal chrome window, insert `chrome://version/` in the search bar, press enter and check from there your profile path.
You will see it will be something like `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 1`

And so in the code you'll have to write:

```
self.options.add_argument(
            r"user-data-dir=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data"
        )
self.options.add_argument("--profile-directory=Profile 1")
```

Comment: It gives me an error `selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: user data directory is already in use, please specify a unique value for --user-data-dir argument, or don't use --user-data-dir` so uh any other solution?

Comment: @Recons Well, reading your error is the first thing you should do! It tells the user data directory is already in use. So... it just means it! You have another chrome page (or many) open with that user logged in. Close all your chrome pages and try again, you'll see it works ;)